# python tools for visual studio: "The current thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be obtained"

Tags: python, ptvs

I am using python tools for visual studio and when I put a breakpoint in the class constructor I get a gray tab saying:

```
No Source Available 
"The current thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be obtained"
```

How to fix that?

Comment: What do you mean by "class constructor"? Can you show a sample code snippet?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Getting a similar issue

Comment: Are you putting the breakpoint on the same line as the def statement?  This might be the cause.